# What is meaning of dialect in the message INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop, dialect

What is the meaning of dialect in the message INFO: Detected dialect: OSS. I am getting this message when I am launching my appium application. And if there is anyway while launching my application I can launch it in dialect W3C. What defines on which dialect will my application launch?